# How to get particular element from an array

Tags: php

I am getting following output from running a php code, now i want to get "url" field from the following array, how can i get this?

```
Array (
    [data] => Array (
        [0] => Array (
            [id] => xxxxx
            [from] => Array (
                [id] => xxxxxx
                [name] => abc
            )
            [start_time] => 2012-04-28T07:49:17+0000
            [end_time] => 2012-04-28T07:49:17+0000
            [publish_time] => 2012-04-28T07:49:17+0000
            [application] => Array (
                [id] => 389407107765872
                [name] => Ki News Social Reader
            )
            [data] => Array (
                [article] => Array (
                    [id] => 10150703062718596
                    [url] => http://example.com
                    [type] => kinewssocialreader:article
                    [title] => story
                )
            )
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How to access arrays should be basic knowledge: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: See the multidimensional arrays [here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_arrays.asp).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Index it like any other array. Looking at the actual source of `print_r` can be much more helpful than seeing it all strung together in one line.

```
$arr['data'][0]['data']['article']['url']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$url=$myArray['data'][0]['data']['article']['url']; //assuming $myArray is array
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
$array['data'][0]['data']['article']['url']
```

if your array variable is called $array.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access the array with its key:

```
$array["key_name"] , $array[$key_name]
```

If you want to access the array with its element order:

```
$array[0], $array[1]
```

If the result of the selection is array, you can continue to use [] to go deeper:

Assume $array["key"] is containing an array, and the array has "another_key" keyed value;

```
$array["key"]["another_key"]
```

will work too.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that I'm reading the data structure correctly, it would be:

```
$variableName['data'][0]['data']['article']['url']
```

Where *$variableName* is the name of the top level array.  The parentheses don't balance, so I can't be 100% sure of the structure.

I've drawn out the structure to look like this.  If this matches your structure, the naming above will work.

```
Array ( 
  [data] => Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
      [id] => xxxxx 
      [from] => Array ( 
        [id] => xxxxxx 
        [name] => abc 
      ) 
      [start_time] => 2012-04-28T07:49:17+0000 
      [end_time] => 2012-04-28T07:49:17+0000 
      [publish_time] => 2012-04-28T07:49:17+0000 
      [application] => Array ( 
        [id] => 389407107765872 
        [name] => Ki News Social Reader 
      ) 
      [data] => Array ( 
        [article] => Array ( 
          [id] => 10150703062718596 
          [url] => http://example.com 
          [type] => kinewssocialreader:article [title] => story
        ) 
      )
    )
  )
)
```